# How to capture meta tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function to populate the meta tag value using JavaScript.

this is my meta tag;

```
<meta my-data-id="home">
```

and the script i tried.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0].getAttribute('my-data-id')
```

But on some pages, my meta tag is not always on position [0]. Is there any other ways to write this?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors): `document.querySelector("meta[my-data-id]").getAttribute("my-data-id")`

You can try this out on SO by running in your browser's JS console:

```
document.querySelector("meta[content]").getAttribute("content");
```

Note that HTML5 only explicitly supports [custom attributes that start with `data-`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute).

Comment: Does your script run before the `<meta>` is rendered?

Comment: No it runs after the meta tag, but i also tried it in the console and getting Null..

Comment: sorry there was something wrong in the script i tried. But now it is working except that it is returning the HTML not the actual tag name.